# Final result code of at-commands does not output

Tags: putty, at-command

why does my LG L40 d170 modem not show the final result code?

ex.

```
AT
OK
AT+CGMI
LG Electronics
```

Shouldn't it be like this?

```
AT
OK
AT+CGMI
LG Electronics

OK
```

i tried 'ATV1' and 'ATQ1', but AFAIK, those are by default.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say why, but your expectations are correct. If it actually does not  give a final result code that is an extremely serious error.

Assuming that the implementation of the `AT+CGMI` command is just wrong and does not issue a final result code, I will suggest sending a command line with one (or more) command following `+CGMI` that hopefully will trigger sending a final result code at the end of processing the command line, e.g.

```
AT+CMGI; V1
```